# how can i rename my init.ora file in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

how can i  rename my init.ora file in oracle?

Comment: I guess you can rename it like any other file. So the question is, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You're in 10g -- you should be using an SPFILE in the first place.

If your PFILE or SPFILE is not in the standard location ($ORACLE_HOME/dbs) with the standard name, you're going to have to specify it in any STARTUP command.